# How do I prompt the user to accept or reject a HTTPS certificate?

Tags: java, android, https

My Android app sends requests to an external HTTP server using the DefaultHttpClient API. I am having trouble switching to HTTPS.

My server uses a self-signed certificate which obviously isn't trusted by default.

When the app connects to the server, I want to show the server certificate's fingerprint to the user and make him accept or reject the certificate.

Is this possible with DefaultHttpClient? If yes, could I see a code snippet showing how it's done.

I have seen many supposed solutions to this and similar problems, but none worked for me.

Comment: "I have seen many supposed solutions to this and similar problems, but none worked for me" -- list them and explain the specific problems you encountered.

Comment: Next time I try and fail, I'll post the specific problem here. The thing is I tried several different approaches last night, and none worked for me, and after I got fed up, I didn't bother to take notes of each supposed solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a working solution. Here's the snippet:

```
public class MySocketFactory implements SocketFactory, LayeredSocketFactory {
private SSLContext mSslContext = null;

{
    try {
        mSslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        TrustManager trustManager = new X509TrustManager() {

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                    throws CertificateException {
                // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                // NOTE : This is where we can calculate the certificate's fingerprint,
                // show it to the user and throw an exception in case he doesn't like it
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                    throws CertificateException {
            }
        };

        mSslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{ trustManager }, new SecureRandom());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public Socket connectSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,
        InetAddress localAddress, int localPort, HttpParams params)
                throws IOException, UnknownHostException, ConnectTimeoutException {

    int connTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getConnectionTimeout(params);
    int soTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getSoTimeout(params);

    SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(localAddress, localPort);
    socket.bind(socketAddress);
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), connTimeout);
    socket.setSoTimeout(soTimeout);

    return socket;
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return mSslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
}

@Override
public boolean isSecure(Socket sock) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    return true;
}



@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,
        boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {

    return mSslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
}
```

}

Then you can instantiate your DefaultHttpClient like so:

```
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
    DefaultHttpClient result = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);


    MySocketFactory mySocketFactory = new MySocketFactory();
    Scheme scheme = new Scheme("https", mySocketFactory, port);

    result.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(scheme);
```

I tried it out and it does work!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible with `DefaultHTTPClient,` because the trust matching happens at a lower level, in the SSL stack (JSSE or OpenSSL or whatever Android uses).

The simplest and cheapest solution is not to use a self-signed certificate at all. Use a CA-signed certificate. You've already spent more than it will cost, and you will spend far more in time that it can possibly be worth. Pay the money to a CA.

Comment: Are you saying "it isn't possible" because you know it for a fact or just because you don't know the answer? I am asking because I already know how to make DefaultHttpClient use the app's custom keystore, where trust matching also happens at a lower level, so the reason you provide doesn't fully convince me. Also, my app is meant to be used in conjunction with the user's personal, DynDNS-enabled Raspberry Pi server, so it's impossible to know in advance which certificate is used. That's why I want the user be able to accept or reject by fingerprint.